# How to remoltly access my local home ubuntu machine from outside my local netwok usign VNC

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I want to remotely access my home ubuntu machine using VNC. I have followed the link here [How To Configure Remote Access To Your Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.howtoforge.com/configure-remote-access-to-your-ubuntu-desktop/#comments)

Now, I can remote access using the internal network.  I enabled port forwarding on my spectrum home router from port 5900 to internal ip address of the ubuntu machine and port # 5900 as shown in the screenshot below. However, when using vnc to connect to (mypublicaddress::5900), I was not able to log in. What should I do to be able to remotly access using the public address of my home router

[image: port forwarding]